# Linux shell: test if current directory has been deleted in case of it's re creation

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I know this is not a usual thing to ask here, but may be someone already discovered a trick to test that.

I am using Linux Mint bash terminal and time to time the current directory becomes recreated because of outside actions. After the current directory is recreated outside, all commands like `echo blabla > blabla` fails because terminal holds the current directory handle open and user can not create files in a removed directory holded by opened handle which one became removed outside.

I know `cd .` could restore the handle of the current directory back to created one.

Is there a way to test the current directory handle holded by a terminal on a deleted state before call to `cd .`?

Comment: Could be a question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: Meh. Shell scripting is on topic here too.

Answer (score 4):

Due to race conditions, testing for this condition is a bad idea.

Nevertheless because it's hard to trap, I give you the following:

```
checkcd()
{
    CINODE=$(ls -id . | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    PINODE=$(ls -id `pwd` | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    if [ $? -gt 0 ]
    then
           echo "Current directory is gone"
    elif [ $CINODE -ne $PINODE ]
    then
           echo "Current directory has been deleted and recreated; do cd `pwd` to fix"
    else
           echo "Current directory is ok"
    end if
}
```

There, now it's a function you can put into `.bashrc` and invoke as `checkcd`.

If you need to know how to use `.bashrc` here's your answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I planned to use it manually, not to automate it, so i think this would be hard to write each time :)

Comment: @Andry: Ok use .bashrc

Comment: I suggest to replace `ls -id . | cut -d ' ' -f 1` with `stat --printf "%i" .`.